# I want to change the role of the message sender in discord js

Tags: discord.js

I looked up a lot of information on Google, but I can not change the role of the sender of the message.

```
    client.on('message', message => {

  var tmp;
  for(i=0; i<filter.length; i++){
    tmp = message.content.indexOf(filter[i]);
    if(tmp >= 0){
      message.reply("warning !");
      client.channels.get('395169643553095702').send(message.author.username + "warning !");

      // change roles



      return;
    };
  };
});
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change a user's role, two things must happen first:

1. This user must be a server (guild) member.
2. A role must be created for that guild.

Going through [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs) I found that you first must [create a role within the guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) with the desired [role options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleData), and then [assign the role to a guild member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole).

---

EDIT:
OP has researched this question even further and got a more simple solution:

By simply finding the role you want to add

```
 var role = message.guild.roles.find("name", "RoleName");
```

And then applying it on the proper 'GuildMember' object derived from 'message':

```
message.member.addRole(role);
```

This is assuming the role you are looking for already exists and that the message for sure came from a guild member user.

---

It's likely to look like:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  var tmp;
  for(i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
    tmp = message.content.indexOf(filter[i]);
    if(tmp >= 0) {
      message.reply("warning !");
      client.channels.get('395169643553095702').send(message.author.username + "warning !");
      message.guild.fetchMember(message.author).then(guildMember => {
        // Role should already exist at this point in a more stratigic place in code.
        var desiredRole = message.guild.createRole(.......);
        guildMember.addRole(desiredRole);
        // .....
      }, err => {
        // User is not a member of the guild
      });
      return;
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: But, I found a simpler way.
I hope it will help many people.

 var report =  message.guild.roles.find ( "name", "ReportMember"); 
 message.member.addRole (report);

Comment: Well, good job! You should always chase better and more efficient ways to achieve your desired goals. I will add this to my answer.